# How to exclude users with multiple options sql

Tags: sql

Trying to retrieve just users that don't have a disabled campaign, where `disabled = 1`.

A user can have a disabled campaign and a non-disabled campaign, but if they have any disabled campaigns I want to exclude them from my final result.

Thinking I need something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   user_id,
   CASE
      WHEN
         disabled = 1 
      THEN
         'Disabled' 
      ELSE
         'Good' 
   END
   AS campaign_disabled
```

But this just returns two rows for each `user_id`, one being `Good` and the other `campaign_disabled`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the users that have `disabled = 0` for all their campaigns, so the max value of the column `disabled` must be `0`:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MAX(disabled) = 0
```

Comment: Hmm, that's still returning a user that has both disabled = 0 and disabled = 1 campaigns, granted it's only returning = 0 but running a separate query to see the campaigns that are disabled and they show up in both

Comment: `MAX(disabled) = 0` guarantees that there are not any disabled = 1 for that user. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: Yep, thanks that worked. My other query was incorrect thanks for the help!